# using com dll from unmanaged c++ fails with REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG

Tags: c++, dll, com

I'm really stuck with this and after spending hours of time with google and such I need to ask here because I'm out of ideas...

Using [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/202460/using-COM-dll-in-a-c-console-application) example I currently have this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
// get ATL's client templates
#include <atlcomcli.h>
// import the typelibrary direct from the dll
#import "FibuSvrDLL.dll" raw_interfaces_only no_namespace

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // declare com ptr
    CComPtr<_Server> comInterfacePtr;

    // cocreate an instance
    HRESULT r = comInterfacePtr.CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(Server));
    // this always fails with REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG
}
```

`_Server` seems to be the right interface and `Server` is its coclass. See here the corresponding snippet from generated tlh File:

```
struct __declspec(uuid("5f3a9f5c-196d-4e4c-b339-6664c1c7f4f9"))
/* dual interface */ _Server;
struct /* coclass */ Server;
```

If I use the same DLL from within c# it works out of the box:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using fnSrvDLL5r;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public Program()
        {
            try {
                Server server = new Server();
                server.set_Konfiguration("...");
                [...]
```

The DLL is part of a 3rd party application I've no control of. All I know is that it's written in VB6.

Before I was able to use the DLL from within above c# code I need to use regsvr32 at first. Maybe this is of any help.

Regards, Martin

Comment: Is the COM server registered?

Comment: Use SysInternals' Process Monitor, you'll see your program searching the registry and not finding the key.  Do so for both your C# app and your C++ app, the differences will be easily visible.

Comment: Can it be that your C++ program is 64-bit, but the server is 32-bit?

Comment: @HansPassant using PM I can see that the c# program is doing a lot of reg-stuff while the c++ program calls only a few keys and as far as I can see the c++ program isn't searching for any CLSID. PM only captured ~250 packets for c++ while capturing several thousands for c#.

Comment: @Nikolay as far as I can see yes. The target is Win32

Comment: What I mean that if the program and the DLL have different platforms, then this could be the case (they just read from different registry hives). But if they are both Win32 (x86) then this can't be an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code as shown doesn't call `CoInitialize()` or `OleInitialize()`.  You will never succeed without calling those first.